# Need to edit Google script to copy a row and move to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Right now this script is erasing the data in the row and deleting the row after moving the row to the other sheet. The idea is to keep the data on the row and just copy over the row when the commissions have been verified. The companies and products our business is paid on, stays consistent. So I want this script to copy the row and keep it in the original sheet so that I can edit the cells we enter in how much we were paid each month.

```
function Reporting() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('SunLife');
  var range = s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues() 

  for(i=s.getMaxRows()-2;i>0;i--){  
    var cell = range[i][0]  

    if(cell == 'Yes') { 
      var row = s.getRange(2+i,1).getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reporting");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    }else{continue}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use the moveTo function. Replace the last two lines inside your if statement:

> var data = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
>   targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,numColumns).setValues(data);